# Отменить вращение экрана

Tags: android, activity

Подскажите как отменить вращение Активити, 
 использую вот этот код

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
               android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

но вращение не блокируется

Comment: А `configChanges` не используете?

Comment: Подозреваю, что у вас там есть что-то вроде `android:configChanges="orientation`.

Comment: Не нужно подтверждать отдельным ответом, что работает предложенный другим участником ответ. Для этого отметьте работающий ответ как верный (галочка слева от вопроса, под стрелками).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В метод `onCreate`, вроде бы так

```
setRequestedOrientation (Activity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
//для альбомного режима
```

или

```
setRequestedOrientation (Activity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
//для портретного режима
```